# Prevent map from repositioning when clicking a marker (Google Map v3)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, slide

Markers open a window containing a couple paragraphs of text.  When users click a marker, the map repositions itself (typically shifting the map north) to display the pop-up.

Is there a method for preventing this repositioning action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the disableAutoPan option:

```
infowindow.setOptions({disableAutoPan: true});
```

[**Documentation here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions)