# marker.setPosition() when infowindow is open brings the marker into view - how to stop this?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have Google Maps with Javascript API with a single marker on it.  This single marker has an infowindow showing.

When I call `marker.setPosition()` to move the marker, if the infowindow is open, and the marker is off-screen, then the map pans to bring the marker and infowindow into view.

How can I stop this behavior?  I want to move the marker, but leave it off screen, and leave the map position where it is.

If I close the infowindow, then calling `marker.setPosition()` doesn't pan the map.  The unwanted behavior only happens when the infowindow is open.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent map from repositioning when clicking a marker (Google Map v3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596635/prevent-map-from-repositioning-when-clicking-a-marker-google-map-v3)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing Google Maps Move After Displaying Infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404948/preventing-google-maps-move-after-displaying-infowindow)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps: How to prevent InfoWindow from shifting the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488999/google-maps-how-to-prevent-infowindow-from-shifting-the-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, info windows will pan the map so that they are fully visible when they're open. You could set `disableAutoPan` to `true` on the `InfoWindowOptions` that are set on `google.maps.InfoWindow` when created. For example, where you declare your info window:

```
let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "Blah Blah Blah",
      // other code ...
      disableAutoPan: true
});
```

API Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindowOptions.disableAutoPan

Comment: Yep, it really was that simple.  Cheers!